# Totally ramified extensions of local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, class-field-theory, local-field

I'm trying to solve two exercises from a former course on Local Fields & Class Field Theory. Here is the original [exercise sheet](https://akoelschbach.github.io/Zettel5.pdf).

**Definition** a field extension $L/K$ of non-archimedian local fields $(L, \pi)$ is totally ramified iff $L$ and $F$ have the same residue fields $O_L/(\pi)=k_L=k_K=O_K/(t)$; this is equivalent to existence of a $c \in O_L^*$ with $t= c \cdot \pi^d$ with $d=[L:K]$.

[image]

**Questions**:

In don't know how solve 2.(a) & (b).

Below I would like present my "approach"  in order to solve (a). The main problem in (a) for me is that I don't know how to use the condition that the degree $d$ of the extension is coprime to characteristic $p$ of the residue fields $k_L=k_F$.

My approach on (a): We have to show the existence of a $a \in K$ with $L= K(\sqrt[d]{a})$.

We know by assumption that $O_L/(\pi)=k_L=k= \mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=p^n$ and that we can find a a $c \in O_L^*$ with uniformizer $t= c \cdot \pi^d$. Again, by assumption, $d$ is coprime to $p$. How does it help to find a appropriate root? Again, as $L/K$ is t.r. we know that $L=K(\pi)$ and thus there exist a irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$ of degree $d$ with $f(\pi)=0$. If $f$ has the shape $f= X^d-r, r \in K$ we are done.

The key seems to find a $s \in L$ such that $(\pi \cdot s)^d \cdot c= \pi^d \cdot (s^d \cdot c)= r \cdot t$ such that $s^d \cdot c, r \in O_K^*$ that is is seems to be reasonable to try to modify $\pi$ and $c$. Does anybody see how this can be done or how to continue? Possibly by another approach?

On (b) I have no idea, especially the part that is $L/K$ is cyclic extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $L/K$ totally tamely ramified of degree $d$

$$O_K/(\pi_K) \cong \Bbb{F}_q,\qquad \pi_L^d= \pi_K u,\qquad u \in O_L^\times,\qquad u = \zeta_{q-1}^l(1+a\pi_L), \qquad a\in O_L$$

$$\varpi_L = \pi_L (1+a\pi_L)^{-1/d}\in O_L,\qquad \varpi_L^d = \pi_K\zeta_{q-1}^l=\varpi_K \in O_K$$
$$O_L = O_K[\varpi_K^{1/d}]$$

Iff $d | q-1$ then $\zeta_d\in O_L$ so $O_L/O_K$ is Galois and since $\zeta_d\in O_K$ it is abelian.

Comment: one step I not understand: when you define $\varpi_L = \pi_L (1+a\pi_L)^{-1/d}\in O_L$, what is $(1+a\pi_L)^{-1/d}$? I not understand why taking $d$-th root in $O_L$ is well defined?

Comment: The coefficients of $(1+x)^{-1/d}=\sum_n {-1/d\choose n} x^n$ are rational numbers with denominator not divisible by $p$, thus it is in $\Bbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ or $\Bbb{F}_p[[x]]$ (depending on if $char(K)=0$ or $p$). This is the explicit form of Hensel lemma for $d$-th roots.

Comment: Brief but very impressive for me

Comment: Where did we apply the condition $\gcd(d, q)=1$? Without this assumption, where does the proof go wrong?

Comment: Yes @NeoTheComputer

Comment: Could you please guide me on "where did you use this assumption $\gcd(d, q)=1$?"

Comment: When taking the $d$-th root

Comment: Order of $\zeta_{q-1}^l$ is a divisor of $q-1$, and this order is always prime to $q$. I can not understand how taking $d^{th}$ root of $(1+a\pi_L)^{-1}$ would cause a problem to your proof.

Comment: Try with $3^{1/2}, 3\in \Bbb{Q}_2$

Comment: All that I realized is: $\sqrt{3} \not\in \mathbb{Q}_2$, because $x^2-3$ does not have a solution module $4$ (and higher powers). I can not get the point.

Comment: HENSEL LEMMA. We want the $d$-th root to be in the same field.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe it is too easy, but I can not get the point yet.

Comment: If $\gcd(d, q)=1$, then why we have the $d^{th}$ root in the field?

Comment: Your comments don't make sense. If $L/K$ is totally ramified of degree $d$ then $O_L=O_K[\pi_L]$. Here we want to modify $\pi_L$ slightly to get that it is a $d$-th root of some uniformizer of $O_K$. This works only when $p\nmid d$. This is why the word tamely ramified was invented. If $d|q-1$ (where $q=q_K=q_L$) then the extension is also Galois and abelian.